# How do I use cookies to redirect a returning user to a different page?

Tags: java, redirect, cookies

I've found some similar questions but none are specific to my needs.

I want to set a cookie on mobile devices that visit a coupon page.

The user may visit the coupon page as often as they like.

They will be required to have their waitress/cashier or themselves press a redeem button on the coupon page once they use it.

I want this redeem button to place a cookie for "x" amount of days.
This cookie will redirect this user to an "Already Redeemed Coupon" page during the specified number of days.

How do I set such a cookie or do I need to use java or....?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What stack are you on? What mobile devices are you targeting? You have to flesh out this question a little bit more before it can be adequately answered.

Comment: Also setting a cookie doesn't redirect. You have to set a cookie, and redirect. Thses are two different operations.